# Getting data from XML doc using Excel 2010 VBA, node length returns 0 when node is present

Tags: xml, excel, api, vba

I'm trying to develop a VBA script that takes the ISSN number of journal titles from an excel 2010 spreadsheet, and query the Sherpa/Romeo web service (a copyright policy database). It then populates the spreadsheet with self-archiving policy for each title.

While it works for most of the rows in my test spreadsheet, I can't seem to get the information for a bunch of journal titles. Coincidentally they're all of one publisher, I'm not sure it'd make any difference because it's XML. I think there must be something wrong with my code but I cannot determine why it thinks "resp.getElementsByTagName("journal").Length" as 0 when the journal tag is present. [Here's the link to the XML result for an ISSN that didn't work as expected](http://sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/api29.php?ak=PQ2mALMLxMs&issn=0387-7604).  I tried to compare it with the result of the ones that worked, I can't see any difference.

I'm new to all this, any tips would be greatly appreciated. I hope someone can help :)

Here's a list of ISSNs, I put ** next to the ones that have data within the "journal" tag but didn't get picked up.

```
0387-7604 **
1864-7782
1932-6203
0927-5568
0302-9743
1687-725X
0302-9743
0387-7604
0302-9743
1871-5192 **
1448-0220
1550-2783
1466-853X **
1438-4639 **
1642-431X
0142-0615
0096-140X
1746-1391
1096-3480
1065-9471
0260-2938
1055-9965
1084-8045 **
```

My code:

```
Private Sub btnCopyright_Click()
Dim wsISSN As Worksheet
Set wsISSN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ISSN_2")
Dim ISSN As String
Dim URL As String
Dim baseURL As String
baseURL = "http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/api29.php?" 'I removed my API key' 

Dim i As Integer
Dim Last As Integer

i = 1
Last = wsISSN.Range("D6000").End(xlUp).Row
If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub

For i = 2 To Last 'second row to last row'
    Dim req As New xmlhttp
    ISSN = Cells(i, 4).Value

    If ISSN = "Invalid" Or ISSN = "" Then
        GoTo skipISSN
    End If

    URL = baseURL & "&issn=" & ISSN
    req.Open "GET", URL, False
    req.Send
    Debug.Print (req.ResponseText)

    Dim resp As New DOMDocument
    resp.LoadXML req.ResponseText
    Debug.Print (resp.getElementsByTagName("journal").Length)

    If resp.getElementsByTagName("journal").Length = 0 Then
        Cells(i, 5).Value = "unknown"
        Cells(i, 6).Value = "unknown"
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "unknown"
        Cells(i, 8).Value = "unknown"
        Cells(i, 9).Value = "unknown"
        Cells(i, 10).Value = "unknown"
        Cells(i, 11).Value = "unknown"
        GoTo skipISSN
    End If

        Dim preprint As String
        Dim preRest As String

        Debug.Print (resp.getElementsByTagName("prearchiving").Length)
        If resp.getElementsByTagName("prearchiving").Length = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 5).Value = "-"
        Else
            preprint = resp.SelectSingleNode("//preprints/prearchiving").Text
            If preprint = "can" Then
                Cells(i, 5).Value = "Yes"
            ElseIf preprint = "restricted" Then
                Cells(i, 5).Value = "restricted"
            Else
                Cells(i, 5).Value = "unknown"
            End If
        End If

        'any restrictions for archiving preprint?'
        Debug.Print (resp.getElementsByTagName("prerestrictions").Length)
        If resp.getElementsByTagName("prerestrictions").Length = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 6).Value = "-"
        Else
            preRest = resp.SelectSingleNode("//preprints/prerestrictions").Text
            Debug.Print (preRest)
            If preRest <> "" Then
                Cells(i, 6).Value = preRest
            Else
                Cells(i, 6).Value = "none"
            End If
        End If

        'is postprint allowed?'
        Dim postprint As String
        Dim postRest As String
        Debug.Print (resp.getElementsByTagName("postarchiving").Length)
        If resp.getElementsByTagName("postarchiving").Length = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 7).Value = "-"
        Else
            postprint = resp.SelectSingleNode("//postprints/postarchiving").Text
            If postprint = "can" Then
                Cells(i, 7).Value = "Yes"
            ElseIf postprint = "restricted" Then
                Cells(i, 7).Value = "restricted"
            Else
                Cells(i, 7).Value = "unknown"
            End If
        End If

        'any restrictions for archiving postprint?'
        Debug.Print (resp.getElementsByTagName("postrestrictions").Length)
        If resp.getElementsByTagName("postrestrictions").Length = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 8).Value = "-"
        Else
            postRest = resp.SelectSingleNode("//postprints/postrestrictions").Text
            Debug.Print (postRest)
            If postRest <> "" Then
                Cells(i, 8).Value = postRest
            Else
                Cells(i, 8).Value = "none"
            End If
        End If

        'is publishers version allowed?'

        Dim allCond As String

        Debug.Print (resp.getElementsByTagName("condition").Length)
        If resp.getElementsByTagName("condition").Length = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 9).Value = "-"
            Cells(i, 10).Value = "-"
            Cells(i, 11).Value = "-"
        Else
            allCond = resp.SelectSingleNode("//conditions").Text
            Debug.Print (allCond)
                If InStr(allCond, "embargo") > 0 Then
                    Cells(i, 9).Value = "maybe"
                    Cells(i, 10).Value = "yes"
                    Cells(i, 11).Value = allCond
                ElseIf InStr(allCond, "Publisher's version/PDF may be used") = 0 Then
                    Cells(i, 9).Value = "no"
                    Cells(i, 10).Value = "-"
                    Cells(i, 11).Value = allCond
                ElseIf InStr(allCond, "Publisher's version/PDF may be used") > 0 Then
                    Cells(i, 9).Value = "yes"
                    Cells(i, 10).Value = "-"
                    Cells(i, 11).Value = allCond
                ElseIf allCond = "" Then
                    Cells(i, 9).Value = "-"
                    Cells(i, 10).Value = "-"
                    Cells(i, 11).Value = "-"
                Else
                    Cells(i, 9).Value = "-"
                    Cells(i, 10).Value = "-"
                    Cells(i, 11).Value = allCond
                End If
            End If

skipISSN:

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: There's an invalid character in the XML - line 98, position 57 - which doesn't match the encoding specified for the document. The encoding should probably be "windows-1252" instead of "ISO-8859-1". In other words, the document being served is not well-formed XML and thus won't parse at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this particular invalid encoding issue, try adapting this code:

```
Sub foo()

Dim URL As String
' access key removed - see link in question for value to use
URL = "http://sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/api29.php?ak=...&issn=0387-7604"

Dim req As New XMLHTTP60
req.Open "GET", URL, False
req.send

Dim resp As New DOMDocument60
resp.validateOnParse = False
resp.setProperty "ProhibitDTD", False

resp.loadXML StrConv(req.responseBody, vbUnicode)
Debug.Print resp.getElementsByTagName("journal").Item(0).XML

Set resp = Nothing
Set req = Nothing

End Sub
```

The important parts are as follows:

- uses the "Microsoft XML, v6.0" objects - `XMLHTTP60` and `DOMDocument60` - rather than the v3.0 objects - `XMLHTTP` and `DOMDocument`
- as a consequence of using `DOMDocument60`, need to explicitly allow DTDs. Also, turn off `validateOnParse`
- rather than using the `ResponseText` from the `XMLHTTP60` object, use `responseBody` (a byte array) and then use `StrConv` to convert from the system's default code page to Unicode

This code should also work for the ISSNs which were being successfully retrieved by the code given in the question

Comment: I amended my code and it's working!! @barrowc thank you so much for your help :)